# jQuery vs CSS Preferred or Accepted Style Best Practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, unobtrusive-javascript

I have the following loading image:

```
<img id="loading" src="loading.gif" />
```

To show/hide it during an AJAX call, I have several solutions. For example, I can hide it by adding a class which corresponds to a CSS style:

```
$('#loading').addClass('hidden');

.hidden { display: none; }
```

Alternatively, I can use jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()`. In this particular example, the latter approach is less verbose.

What scenarios benefit from adding CSS 'on the fly'? I've been reading into 'Unobtrusive JavaScript' which recommends injecting all JS into the DOM using jQuery at $(document).ready().

Is there a best practices approach which cleanly separates CSS and jQuery in a similar manner?

Comment: Maybe a jQuery / unobtrusive JS guru will say otherwise, but I'd say it really doesn't matter, either way is fine (although I find `show` and `hide` more verbose than `addClass` and `removeClass`)

Comment: “… recommends injecting all JS into the DOM using jQuery at $(document).ready()” has nothing to do with your question: most of the time an AJAX call is made after the page is fully loaded (and it is *then* when you want to show/hide your loading indicator).

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I mentioned this to highlight how that technique separates HTML from JS, whereas I am asking if there is a preferred approach of separating JS from CSS - since doing addClass() the JS has to know about the CSS.

Comment: No, that's not true: when an element exists in the DOM, it can be manipulated by JS, e.g., by setting the `class` property. It doesn't matter if the CSS is already loaded or not.

Comment: What I mean is that when you say .addClass('myclassname') you have to know how myclassname is styled in the CSS.

Comment: That's true; using `show()` and `hide()` looks more obvious to me. That said, you really should use meaningful class names; I highly doubt you forget that `.hidden` means "hide an element"; It would be stupid to set `display: block` within `.hidden` (other than for testing purposes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you want to set the initial state from the server side then it would be cleaner to use classes, as that will avoid the necessary client-side initialization (*with possible flashing of the content*).

You also usually use class selectors with jquery, so it is always easier to play with classes (*for me at least*), than trying to figure if a property has been changed in the css of an element.

In the end it boils down to what *you* feel more comfortable working with..